# svn: Aborting commit: 'file.xpm' remains in conflict

Tags: svn, svncommit

I am very new to svn (basically, all I know is how to use things like ci, co, rm, add, stat, and diff, but no technical details) ,and I'm attempting to check in a major chunk of code.

I'm doing a check-in from the very top of things (with "."), like this:

```
svn ci -m "Major check-in of restructured GUI classes." .
```

Unfortunately, this creates the following error with an old icon file that existed at some point:

```
 Aborting commit: '/users/nvjulian/Research/5prog/trunk/src/gui/icon/Board.xpm' remains in conflict
```

I tried to resolve this but was unsuccessful:

```
[nvjulian@dupin trunk]$ svn rm src/gui/icon/Board.xpm
svn: Use --force to override this restriction
svn: 'src/gui/icon/Board.xpm' is not under version control
```

...even when I did it this way:

```
[nvjulian@dupin trunk]$ svn rm --force src/gui/icon/Board.xpm
svn: 'src/gui/icon/Board.xpm' does not exist
```

Indeed, this file doesn't exist; it was deleted a long time ago and I didn't find it anywhere after searching my entire computer. I tried these commands from a variety of directory locations and it still didn't work. Actually, when I first did the svn stat to get ready for the check in, I was met with this:

```
!     C icon/Board.xpm
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
```

So I tried to actually do svn up on that file (?), but still, no success. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `svn resolved icon/Board.xpm` to mark the file as being resolved. Subversion will not allow you to commit your changes as long as it thinks there are unresolved issues.